# Odoo 11 No Module Found

Tags: odoo-11

Hi I am new to odoo and linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I had set up the ubuntu desktop on an oracle vm virtualbox, I have also installed the necessary repository and apt for odoo11, postgresql, python3 and pycharm.

My odoo11 is already working fine and I am able to install and run existing applications, however I have tried to generate a scaffold to develop a module of my own, and I have followed guides and documentations.

My odoo.conf has these options

```
[options]

; This is the password that allows database operations:

; admin_passwd = admin

db_host = False

db_port = False

db_user = odoo

db_password = False

logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log

addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo/addons,/home/mtsoftware/Documents/projects/tutorial/addons
```

while my manifest.py has these option

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "myfirstModel",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/odoo/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/customer.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

Upon trying to search for "myfirstModel" in my module list @ odoo11 application page, it returns a "No module found!"

Any one can help me?

Comment: You need to update modules list before searching for the module in the modules list. you need to enable developer mode in odoo 11 in order to view update modules list button.From any App, open the Help menu (looks like a question mark) and select About Odoo then click Activate Developer Mode.

Comment: Thanks! I have activated and updated my app list, however it seems that the module that I wanted to add is still not there, I'm out of options, may I know it has anything to do with permissions settings on my ubuntu?

Comment: your manifest looks fine, as long as your module has read and write access for openerp user permissions are fine. could you verify the path you have placed your module in ? you could place it in odoo/addons directory.

Comment: I have verified the path that I placed my module in, I did a 'pwd' and copied the working directory into my manifest, thus I am sure it is correct. I did a  'chown -R myname:myname /path/*' too. I did a 'ls -l' and it looks fine to me... i'll try placing it indo odoo/addons